# Streaming part of a video in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, streaming

I'm using a module ([BinaryJS](http://binaryjs.com/)) to pass a video stored in a server to the browser (the client).

My goal is to play not the entire video, but a part.

What I've tried was

```
//Creating the client
var client = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9000/binary-endpoint')

//Inserting the video element in the body
var video = document.createElement("video");
document.body.appendChild(video);

//Array where the arrayBuffers will be stored
var parts =  [];

client.on('stream', function(stream,meta){
  stream.on('data',function(data){
      parts.push(data);
  });
  stream.on('end',function(){
    video.src = (window.URL||window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob(parts.slice(0,500)));
    $('video')[0].play();
    $('video')[0].controls=true;
  })
});
```

Note that, in order of achieve the goal, I've fed the `Blob` constructor with just a part of received data (`parts.slice(0,500)`).

The code above doesn't work, unless I feed the `Blob` with the whole received data - `new Blob(parts)`.

What is the better workaround to this problem?

I appreciate any help.